# fetch facebook user info to another view controller

Tags: ios, facebook, viewcontroller

I have a default's facebook sdk loginViewController, but at all the examples on facebookSDK page, they fetched user info in a same viewController, so what can I do if I want to store all user info (fetched by loginViewController) to use in another viewControllers?

Fetching user code from loginViewController

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
    self.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome,\n %@", user.name];
    NSLog(@"%@ has been got from loginViewFetchedUserInfo function",user.name);
    _loggedInUser = user;
}

// Implement the loginViewShowingLoggedInUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a logged-in user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Click button below to continue";
    [self.logoImage setHidden:YES];
    [self.profilePictureView setHidden:NO];
    [self.continueButton setHidden:NO];
    //[self pushToMainTabsBarController];
}

// Implement the loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a logged-out user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = @"";
    self.statusLabel.text= @"Please login to continue!";
    [self.logoImage setHidden:NO];
    [self.profilePictureView setHidden:YES];
    [self.continueButton setHidden:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the other view controller you just need to insert a property like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FBGraphUser> user;
```

and then for example, when you fetch the user data in the first method, set the property to the new view controller (already instanced obviously):

```
_newViewController.user = user;
```

Or if you want instance the new view controller in another time, you can set the same property in the login view controller to store the user data temporally (as you already are doing with `_loggedInUser = user;`) and then pass it to the new view controller at the right moment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly know how to "set the property to the new view controller (already instanced obviously):". Please explain for me

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in Core Data and then retrieving back in other view or pass it throug the `segue` method like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToOtherViewController"]) {
        OtherViewController *OVC = (OtherViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        OVC.user = user;
    }
}
```

Using Core Data requires a [little reading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).